# Positioning of Polygons in Slick2D

Tags: java, opengl, slick2d

I try to create hexagons and place them on the opengl window. I want to use them as a tiled-map. My current code looks like this:

```
private Polygon generateTile(){
        Polygon poly = new Polygon();
        for(int i = 0; i < 6; ++i) {
            poly.addPoint((float)Math.sin(i/6.0*2*Math.PI),
                    (float)Math.cos(i/6.0*2*Math.PI));
        }
        return poly;
    }

private void generateTiles (){
        Shape s;
        Polygon p = generateTile();
        for (int i = 0; i <= 2; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j <=10; j++) {
                s=p.transform(Transform.createScaleTransform(Constants.TILE_SIZE, Constants.TILE_SIZE));
                if (i%2==0) {
                    s.setLocation(s.getMaxX()*j*2, s.getMaxY()*i*2);
                } else {
                    s.setLocation(s.getMaxX()*j*2+Constants.TILE_SIZE, s.getMaxY()*i*2);
                }

                tiles.add(s);

            }
        }
```

Window:

[image]

The problem is that the row 2 should integrate under row 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*The actual offset of the tile is not its size.*

There is a great article on this [here](http://www.redblobgames.com/grids/hexagons/)

[image: Hex Grid dimensions]